# How do you change the onTouchListener on the same animated image view?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

Just like how those conveyors in some apps that you can swipe to the right to bring out (show it) and then swipe to the left to send back in, hiding it again. I tried using setOnTouchListener again on the same view with a delayed message after it's brought out, but the app receives an error and closes when you try to bring it out (show). If I am to remove the method that is supposed to make it go back in (hidden), it would be brought out just fine, but how do I make it happen that it could be sent back in and hidden  through swiping to the left after it's been brought out by swiping to the right?

Here's the code I used in the activity:

```
ImageView conveyorWheel;
private float x1, x2;
static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;
RelativeLayout parentLayout;
android.os.Handler conveyorHandler;

conveyorWheel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.conveyerWheel);
parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
 parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE & x1 < x2) {

                        conveyorWheel.animate()
                                .x(-750)
                                .setDuration(150)
                                .start();

                        conveyorHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                conveyorRevert();
                            }
                        }, 151);

                        break;

                    }

                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



}

private void conveyorRevert (){
    parentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){

                        conveyorWheel.animate()
                                .x(-950)
                                .setDuration(150)
                                .start();

                        break;
                    }

                default: return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The Android Monitor displayed the error:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)' on a null object reference

But I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Where do you create 'conveyorHandler' parameter?

Comment: I declared it before the onCreate method, on line 5. It appeared to me that android studio now recognizes android.os.Handler as the handler we've been referring to to post delayed messages. I tried using Handler, but it does something completely different now

Comment: 'android.os.Handler conveyorHandler;' is just declaration. You need to create the handler like 'conveyorHandler = new Handler();' somewhere in onCreate.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have missed that one out when learning to create handlers. It works perfectly. Now how do I close the thread where a comment gave the answer?